# dataTaskWithRequest, header autorization, every second request is not executed

Tags: swift, swift2, nsurlsession

I have a problem with header field in `NSMutableURLRequest`, when i added key "authorization" to HTTPHeaderField then exactly every second request is failing to execute.
When is failing i receive error with `NSJSONSerialization` (code = 3840) on parsing response and in server log i haven't any information about incoming connection.
My request is:

```
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://my/end/point")!

let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let key = prefs.valueForKey("accessToken") as! String

request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

request.addValue("key: (\(key))", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { urlData, response, error in
    if(urlData == nil){
        print("\(error)")
    }else {
        do{
            let serialization = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers )
            self.jsonData = serialization as? NSDictionary

            let success:NSInteger = self.jsonData!.valueForKey("success") as! NSInteger

            if(success == 1){
                [...]
            } else {
                print("\(error)")

                print("\( self.jsonData!)")
            }
        }catch{
            print("error with jsonSerialization: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Anyone have any idea whats is wrong with my request?

Edit:
if i delete `request.addValue("key: (\(key))", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")` then everything is ok, i get response from serwer

Comment: looks like it isn't son then. check what `urlData` is as a string...

Comment: let strData = NSString(data: urlData!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
when i get error on prasing response then this is null. Reason of error code = 3840 is a "no value"

Comment: a null string, not `nil` though, otherwise you shouldn't hit the json logic. what is the response error from the http request in this case ?

Comment: error from dataTaskWithRequest everytime is nil, only jsonSerialization return "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}" becouse urlData is empty, becouse task was not sent

Comment: if it wasn't sent you would get an error back. what is the `currentRequest` and `response` ?

Comment: in response i get  "status code: 500, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    Connection = close;
Other is information about serwer
in task,currentRequest i get only url of my serwer
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 20;

Comment: so it did get to the server, and the server threw a hissy fit, you need to look at why

Comment: ok, this was a problem with serwer, thanks for help !